# Attribute values via php not giving a value

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="111">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo (date('F j, Y.')) ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo (time()) ?>">
```

When I send the above values to the server using the post method, it returns blank value on the server using the $_POST, nothing shows up. When I use `alert($form.find("input[name='page']").val())` it display this:

The page at 127.0.0.1 says:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>
```

I am using xampp on my local machine, if knowing this helps contributes to fixing the problem.

The other rest code such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="111">
<input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Your name"/>
```

I get the values for those.

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your server? Is this a php page? How do you call it? It seems like the PHP is not executed at all.

Comment: isn't this obvious that you php code does not execute ?

Comment: I have Xammp server download on my machine. I execute the code by putting the file in htdocs folder. I use this extension: http://127.0.0.1/Glory/review-template.html. I know the code executes because the other $_POST variables are defined in the external PHP file. I use the $.Post(filename, datasend) jquery method - do you want the script for that ?

Comment: Which file has the extension review-template.html? The page that displays "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>"? Because if that's the case its the file extension; the extension must be php.

Comment: I just change the extension to php and it works now. So if there is a php code in your html page, it has to end with .php ?

Comment: Yes. It must always be PHP. I'll post a question to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a file has any form of PHP code in it the extension must be PHP. PHP code will not be executed otherwise.

There are some ways to override this, but you'd have to redefine the mime types and its just not worth the effort. .php is the extension used for PHP pages, and if any PHP code is in your page, just name it .php.

Typically, if I know I'm going to be working with PHP code, I always name all my files .php anyway so I don't have to worry about changing them and messing up my URL's later.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP isn't running. If you have installed it you should be able to start it by going to your *services* window.